# Django; POST request doesn't work when I try to submit invalid data

Tags: python, django

I found out error message doesn't show up for some forms so I tried to do like this.

```
def add_entry(request):

    if request.method != 'POST':
        form = EntryForm(user=request.user)
    else:
        form = EntryForm(request.POST, user=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('blog:list_entry'))
        else:
            print("error happened.")

    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/add_entry.html', context)
```

and even when I tried to submit invalid data, it didn't output anything.

`html`

```
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form.description.errors }}
        <label>{{ form.description.label }}</label>
        {{ form.description|add_class:'form-control' }}
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>
</form>
```

`models.py`

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    description = models.TextField(max_length=512)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

`forms.py`

```
class EntryForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Entry
        fields = ['description']


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user')
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)


    def save(self):
        entry = super().save(commit=False)
        entry.user = self.user
        entry.save()
        return entry
```

When I submit valid data, the form does work. What am I wrong with this?

Comment: Submit valid or invalid data? The title and question seems to contradict each other.

Comment: And if you simply have `form.errors` instead of `form.description.errors`, do you see any errors?

Comment: No, and I mean even when I try to submit invalid data, `print("error happened.")` this line doesn't work. Sorry if the title is confusing. Please edit.

Comment: Please show the definition of the EntryForm, and also specify what "invalid data" you are posting.

Comment: I mean I try to submit with empty filed.

Comment: just to be clear about which flow is happening: is the `add_entry()` view returning the `HttpResponseRedirect` (i.e. `form.is_valid()`) or is it returning the `render()` template response with no errors shown?

Comment: when `form.is_valid()`, all things work as expected. when I try to submit invalid data, even POST request doesn't happen on command prompt. So `print("error happens")` doesn't work as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your browser validation is preventing the form from being submitted when the `description` field is empty.

You can work around this by adding `novalidate` to the form. The browser will then allow you to submit a request with `description=""`, and you should see the error from Django in the response.

```
<form method="POST" novalidate>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form.description.errors }}
        <label>{{ form.description.label }}</label>
        {{ form.description|add_class:'form-control' }}
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>
</form>
```